# What are the current resources for building a Facebook application with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

I'm looking to build a basic Facebook application with Rails. What are the resources (books podcasts, screencasts, blog articles etc) that you'd recommend?

(One answer per post please, and up-vote instead of duplicate).

Comment: Did you mean for this to be community wiki? I see you have already posted your own answer.

Comment: I posted two of the resources that I've found to be useful, thinking that others might also find them useful. Did you have any resources to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Screencast:**
[Rails Development for the Facebook Platform](http://pragprog.com/screencasts/v-mmfacer/rails-development-for-the-facebook-platform), by Michael J. Mangino (screencast published by The Pragmatic Programmers).

Comment: I found these videos to be somewhat useful in the end.

Answer (score 3):

I realise you're writing a Rails app, but here's a link to a very good, recently produced screencast from Remi showing you how to use Sinatra with the Frankie plugin to make an FB app - http://remi.org/2009/12/31/getting-started-with-facebook-development.html -

Yes I know it's not exactly what you're looking for, but it does take you through some of the leg-work on the Facebook side of things, which helps regardless of the programming platform.  You could easily port most of it to Rails without having to think too hard about it.

Comment: It might not have been what the original poster was looking for, but it is exactly what I was trying to find.

Comment: Sigh ! Must be a nice video- but too lazy to create a new login

Answer (score 2):

Facebooker tutorial http://apps.facebook.com/facebooker_tutorial/

Comment: The second page of this tutorial didn't work when I checked it last, and there were complaints in the thread stretching back months.

Comment: @mlambie, totally. I now recommend your answer, http://pragprog.com/screencasts/v-mmfacer/rails-development-for-the-facebook-platform. I'll mark yours +1, too

Comment: This tutorial has been deprecated . http://www.nolanconsul.com/articles/facebooker-tutorial/

Comment: @RN, so where should one look, then?

Answer (score 0):

**Book:** [Developing Facebook Application with Rails](http://pragprog.com/titles/mmfacer/developing-facebook-platform-applications-with-rails), by Michael J. Mangino (published by The Pragmatic Programmers).