# Best way to interact with facebook from a Rails Application

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebooker

What I want to do is automatically post to facebook when a user post something on his profile (inside my app), I want to remember the user facebook credential to post automatically without asking for his credentials again.

Tumblr has already implement this functionality and I want to emulate it.

What is the best way to implement this functionality whitin a rails app?

Comment: Hi, here is a promising stackoverflow thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039475/what-are-the-current-resources-for-building-a-facebook-application-with-rails

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at http://facebooker.rubyforge.org/?

Comment: I'm currently using facebooker but I dont know how to correctly implement the functionality that I described.